# loopback 4 command model is hanging

Tags: node.js, api, strongloop, loopback, loopback4

I am using the command lb4 model but It hangs in my system(windows).

```
   My node -> 12.13.1
   npm -> 6.12.1
   @loopback/cli -> 2.6.0
```

and all dependencies are also installed correctly.
Please can you tell the problem here?
[loopback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krumY.png)

Answer (score 1):

Can you please shot a try for this :-
1) Delete node_modules from the directory.
2) Followed by npm install.
This may fix your lb4 model hang issue. If not revert back with package.json. Thanks